# Sort in list object

Tags: c#, linq

I get from database `Sytem.Collections.generic.IList` and filter it by `searchText`:

```
String searchText="E";
var query = something().List();
query = query.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Name) &&
x.Name.ContainsInsensitive(searchText)).ToList();
result = query.Select().ToList();
```

Now I would like that result is sorted by `Name` column. First all values which starts with `searchText` and then all values which contains `searchText`.

If I write this:

```
result = result.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

I get result sorted by Name, for example:

```
1. "A name"    
2. "B name"
3. "E name"
4. "F name"
```

All this contains `e` in `Name`. I would like that my sort is:

```
1. "E name"    
2. "A name"
3. "B name"
4. "F name"
```

What should I change in my `OrderBy` expression?

Comment: I don't think that's possible by default. Sorting on string works differently

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh - very little is possible "by default". That's where the programming bit comes in ;)

Comment: I skipped the `searchText` section. Yes. true.

Answer (score 13):

Chain together 2 orders with `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`

```
.OrderBy(x => x.Name.StartsWith(searchText) ? 0 : 1)
.ThenBy(x => x.Name)
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do two sorting calls after another (first `OrderBy`, all subsequent `ThenBy`):

```
result.OrderBy(x => !x.Name.StartsWith(searchText)).ThenBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

This will sort true (1) first, then (0) false. The `!x.Name` makes the order right. Then it sorts on `x.Name` in both groups.

Answer (score 3):

Well, according your code you have `result` *materialized* as `List<T>`:

```
 result = query.Select().ToList();
```

And then you're *recreating* and *reassigning* the list:

```
 result = result.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

So I suggest sorting `in-place` instead of `OrderBy`:

```
  result.Sort((x, y) => {
    if (x.Name.StartsWith(searchText)) {
      if (!y.Name.StartsWith(searchText))
        return 1;
    } 
    else if (y.Name.StartsWith(searchText))
      return -1;

    return String.Compare(x.Name, y.Name);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you care about is the index of search string. so the string that matches `searchText` sooner would become first. here is example:

```
String searchText = "E";
List<string> result = new List<string>
{
    "B name",
    "A name",
    "E name",
    "FE name",
};


result = result.OrderBy(x => x.IndexOf(searchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ThenBy(x=>x).ToList();
```

You will get

```
"E name",
"FE name",
"A name",
"B name",
```

But if its not what you look for then use `StartsWith` like in other answers.

Comment: That is a nice approach I didn't think of yet. The problem is, it doesn't sort the rest as expected, since `A` sorts after `FE` now.

Comment: @PatrickHofman it sorts first based on `searchText`. `A name` has `e` at last position but `FE name` has `e` at second position so it become before `A name`

Comment: I know, but this might not be what OP expects.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more accurate:

```
result.OrderByDescending(x=>Regex.Split(x.Name, searchText, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count()).ToList();
```

Or even better:

```
result.OrderByDescending(x => 
    Regex.Split(x.Name, searchText, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    .Sum(el => el.StartsWith(searchText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ? 1 : 0)
).ToList();
```

Comment: So why is it more accurate? Where does it check 'starts with', as asked by OP?

Comment: because maybe the second word would start with E and should be before another item whose second word starts with A or any other letter.

Comment: I think you've creeped the requirements somewhat!

Comment: i wrote down a solution based on how I would organize my search in a database full of names. Actually the way I would do it is more complex to assure a proper order by giving a rating to each result.